# How to make the image responsive inside a table-cell (td)

Tags: html, css, vue.js, html-table

I have a table in a VueJs project, the `td` looks like this

```
<tr class="bg-grey">
  <td class="row-border" v-for="(subItem, subIndex) in item.items">
     <img :src="subItem.image" v-show="subItem.image" style="width:100%" />
        <label class="btn-block" v-show="!subItem.image">
           <div class="flex-center">
             <img src="/img/icons/ils/add-image.png" class="image-icon" />
           </div>
           <input
             type="file"
             accept="image/*"
             capture="environment"
             class="d-none"
             @change="e => showItemImage(e, item, subIndex)"
            />
         </label>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Here's how it looks like in the browser:

[image]

Now after I click one of those camera icons, I can select the file, then it looks like this:

[image]

Now you can see how big the first `td` grew, because it had an image, and others had the same old camera image. What I want to do is to make all the `td`'s widths even.

Can anyone please tell me what is the problem here?columns don't maintain the same height.

Comment: And do note, `td` in a `table` doesn't wrap line, and if you need to wrap every 2nd, why at all use `table`? ... and btw, Flexbox do maintain elements the same height on the same row, just like a table does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, once you load an image, it has larger dimensions than the camera icon. The table adapts its layout accordingly.

You need to set the width of each table cell to 33%.